# Show form modal on top of another process

Tags: c#

I've tried doing that, and ended up with the following code;

```
        var proc = Process.GetProcesses().Where(x => x.ProcessName == "notepad").First();
        IWin32Window w = Control.FromHandle(proc.MainWindowHandle);

        using (Form2 frm = new Form2())
        {
            frm.ShowDialog(w);
        }
```

However, that doesn't display the form as a modal on top of "notepad", for some reason, why's that?
What I want to achieve is: Being able to display a modal on top of notepad. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [ShowDialog on top of another process?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18286709/showdialog-on-top-of-another-process)

Comment: Edit your existing questions instead of a new question

Answer (score 2):

`Control.FromHandle` will return null for windows created in another process.

So when calling `frm.ShowDialog(w);` you're actually passing `null` hence your form is not parented by `Notepad's window`.

```
public class Win32WindowWrapper : IWin32Window
{
    private IntPtr handle;
    public Win32WindowWrapper(IntPtr handle)
    {
        this.handle = handle;
    }
    public IntPtr Handle
    {
        get { return handle; }                
    }
}

using (Form2 frm = new Form2())
{
    frm.ShowDialog(new Win32WindowWrapper(proc.MainWindowHandle));
}
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

You need convert IntPtr to IWin32Window, but to do that you are obliged to use a wrapper. Here's the sample source code:

```
public class WindowWrapper : System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window
{
    public WindowWrapper(IntPtr handle)
    {
        _hwnd = handle;
    }

    public IntPtr Handle
    {
        get { return _hwnd; }
    }

    private IntPtr _hwnd;
}

Process[] procs = Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad");
if (procs.Length != 0)
{
    IntPtr hwnd = procs[0].MainWindowHandle;
    MessageBox.Show(new WindowWrapper(hwnd), "Hello World!");
}
else
    MessageBox.Show("Notepad is not running.");
```

Source: http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/03/23/465.aspx